# Correct way to set server based values in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have some server side variables that I'd like to show in the Vuex store.

Most of the documentation seems to revolve around all values already being in the `store.js` before you begin.

Would the correct way passing them to Vuex be something like:

```
<script>
   const MODEL_ID = 1234567;
</script>
<script src="/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

And then referenced from the `app.bundle.js`, in my `store.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    modelId: MODEL_ID,
  }
});
```

I know it will work it just seems very inelegant.

Comment: maybe use 1 object to store all the initial state, so that the global scope is less polluted ...

Comment: Most of the time the data will be coming from either API calls or passed into components via props. Your code example does not really show at what exact point you need your `MODEL_ID` so it is hard to tell if this can be improved. (Also I would change `const` to `var` since that is probably not going through an ES6 transpiler)